# Different Navigation Menus for Controller Views - Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I currently have 3 controllers, `AdministratorController.php`, `ResellerController.php` and `ServiceProviderController.php`.

Each of these have their own actions and views. For instance, `AdministratorController.php` has the views:

[image]

Each of these controllers' views will have exactly the same layout - the only difference in layout being different navigational menus.

So my question is, how I can configure different navigational menus for controllers, but using the same layout?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personnaly, my navigation menu is stored in an XML file. When I create my "Zend_Navigation", I load only on part of my navigation menu like this :

```
$navigation = new Zend_Navigation(new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', $controllerName));
$view->navigation($navigation);
```

Where "$controllerName" is a section of my "navigation.xml".

In your view:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(); ?>
```

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks Akarun. I'm currently passing an array to the View through the controller's Init which isn't ideal. Will experiment with your technique and see how it goes!  Cheers.